# Updating a list in ionic modal updates original list ionic 5

Tags: html, angular9, ionic5

I have a clarification, Basically i am passing a list from parent page to Ionic modal. In modal, i will iterating over a list. i am basically modifying a property of an object on click of ion-item.

Below is the html code in the modal.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="3">
        <ion-img width="80" height="80" [src]="item.imagePath"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="7" >
       <ion-label class="item-name">item.name</ion-label>
       <ion-label class="item-price">item.cost</ion-label>
       <ion-label class="item-date">item.date</ion-label>        
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="2">
       <ion-icon class="select-icon" name="add-circle" (click)="updateObj(item)"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
   </ion-card>
```

In modal.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.navParams.get("items");
  }

  dismissModal(){
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }
  
  updateObj(object){
     if(object){
      object.status = true
    }
  }
```

i am using navParams to get the list from parent page to the modal. When i click on ion-item i will be calling updateObj method where i am updating the status of object to true. Everything works fine.
But when i update the object in the modal, the original list sent to the modal also gets updated.

**Could anyone explain why updating the list in the modal updates the original list. Is it bcoz of using navParams as it referers to the list?**

In Parent.component.ts

```
async openSearchModal(){
  const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
    component: CouponSearchPage,
    componentProps: { items: this.itemListData,
   }
  });
```

This is how i am passing the list to the modal from parent screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass this.itemListData to modal, you are passing the reference of the object.
If you don't want to modify the actual object, you can pass a new object.
Try this:

```
  const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
    component: CouponSearchPage,
    componentProps: { items: { ...this.itemListData},
   }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you please help me with the below query also??        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670383/ionic-tab-icons-not-showing-for-android-6-and-below

Comment: I have an issue in displaying icons for below android 6.