# Ionic Tab Icons not showing for Android 6 and Below

Tags: angular8, capacitor, ionic5

I have a created ionic tabs with icons. Icons are correctly displayed for Android 7 and above, But below Android 6, few icons are not getting displayed. Below is the screenshot for the same.
I am using ionic 5 and capacitor version 2.1.2

i tried with reorder and list. Both these icons are not shown for below android 6. Above android 7 it works.

Am i missing something?

Android 6 screenshot :

[image]

Android 7 and above

[image]

Tabs code :

```
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
         <!-- <ion-icon name="pricetag-outline"></ion-icon>-->
         <ion-icon name="pricetag"></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button>
    
 /*Using the SVG locally, still doesn't display for android 6 and below. Works fine for Android 7 and above.*/ 
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
         <!-- <ion-icon name="reorder-four-outline"></ion-icon>-->
         <ion-icon class="staticIcon" src="/assets/icon/list.svg" ></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button>
    
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
         <!-- <ion-icon name="location-outline"></ion-icon>-->
         <ion-icon name="location"></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button>
    
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab4">
         <!-- <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>-->
         <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
```

Comment: same issue here. I guess it's related to css compatible issue. 'stroke' css maybe doesn't work in old Android webview in Android5&6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/assets/icon/list.svg">
  Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Comment: What is the <object> here??

Comment: you can use <object> to load external resources. your svg file ca be loaded with object tag.

Comment: No, it didn't work. But the issue was that when we  do ionic build  and npx cap sync android all the assets will be copied  to www folder. Few icons though it exists under svg folders but didn't have any icons hence was not showing.

Comment: could you please help me with issue @gunjan?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993421/jsbarcode-integration-with-ionic-5